# What is the difference between special logon & logon?

Tags: windows-7

This two words you can find on event viewer in some windows operating systems, please can anybody tell what are there?

Answer (score 2):

### What makes a logon 'special'?

Special logons relate to administrator-level sessions, see the [Technet explanation here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772635%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> A special logon is used. A special logon is a logon that has administrator-equivalent privileges and can be used to elevate a process to a higher level.

There is also [some discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8bf6a0aa-2069-4bf0-abdd-f7fb84e07aae/lots-of-special-logon-events-for-computer-account?forum=winservergen) at the Technet answers site about having lots of these:

> This is a useful right to detecting any "super user" account logons.  Of course this right is logged for any server or applications accounts logging on as a batch job (scheduled task) or system service.

*(per answer by Miles Zhang)*

### So what about other logon events?

You can see a fuller [explanation of those events over at Technet again](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> ...Additionally, interactive logons to a member server or workstation that use a domain account generate a logon event on the domain controller as the logon scripts and policies are retrieved when a user logs on.

Basically, when you log in, you generate logon events. There are different types:

```
2    Interactive        A user logged on to this computer.
3    Network            A user or computer logged on to this computer from the network.
4    Batch              Batch logon type is used by batch servers, where processes may be executing on behalf of a user without their direct intervention.
5    Service            A service was started by the Service Control Manager.
7    Unlock             This workstation was unlocked.
8    NetworkCleartext   A user logged on to this computer from the network. The user's password was passed to the authentication package in its unhashed form. The built-in authentication packages all hash credentials before sending them across the network. The credentials do not traverse the network in plaintext (also called cleartext).
9    NewCredentials     A caller cloned its current token and specified new credentials for outbound connections. The new logon session has the same local identity, but uses different credentials for other network connections.
10   RemoteInteractive  A user logged on to this computer remotely using Terminal Services or Remote Desktop.
11   CachedInteractive  A user logged on to this computer with network credentials that were stored locally on the computer. The domain controller was not contacted to verify the credentials.
```

Most will be either 2 (interactive) or 3 (network) or 7 (unlock).

Comment: I wonder what happened to the missing logon type `1`?

Comment: Lost in the mists of time ;-)